# Voyager - laravel admin panel

Tags: laravel-routing

My question is related to controller in Voyager admin panel. For example I created a table with migration . It's name was "groups" and then I created BREAD and added it to menu in Voyager.

I created a folder that it's name is "groups" in \resources\views\vendor\voyager andthen I created two file to override the view.

But I do not know where the controller is . I created controller with php artisan make:controller GroupsController. I guess this controller is not related to voyager controllers.

I want to change the index or create method and pass some data to views in controller but I do not know where it is.

I created a controller in \vendor\tcg\voyager\src\Http\Controllers that it's name is VoyagerGroupsController.php but when I create class and index method in it , it does not work.

How can I create controller for "groups" and pass the data to the view?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever we create a table in voyager, Voyager calls it datatype. And for all tables / datatypes created by us, Voyager users only one controller **VoyagerBreadController.php** located at **vendor\tcg\voyager\src\Http\Controllers**.

For example, if I create a table named **brands**. Laravel will use controller **VoyagerBreadController**.

But where are the routes which use or point to this controller. Routes are located in file **vendor\tcg\voyager\routes\voyager.php**. In this file, find the following lines:

```
try {
            foreach (\TCG\Voyager\Models\DataType::all() as $dataTypes) {
                Route::resource($dataTypes->slug, $namespacePrefix.'VoyagerBreadController');
            }
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Custom routes hasn't been configured because: ".$e->getMessage(), 1);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // do nothing, might just be because table not yet migrated.
        }
```

In my version, these lines are between line No. 29 to 37.

As you can see, above code is fetching all our datatypes and creating a resouce route for our tables / datatypes.

Now, if I want to **override** this route and create a route to use my own controller for a particular action. For example, if I want to create a route for brands/create url. I can do this by simply adding following line (my route) below above code (i.e. after line 37):

```
Route::get('brands/create', function(){return 'abc';})->name('brands.create');
```

or you can do the same by adding following line in **routes\web.php** after Voyager::routes();

```
Route::get('brands/create', function(){return 'abc';})->name(**'voyager.brands.create'**);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's now it's using your App controller not a Voyager controller so you have to override your full controller

like

In config/voyager.php add

```
'controllers' => [
'namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers',
],
```

Create new controller like MyBreadController.php into App/controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class MyBreadController extends \TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
//code here
}

app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

use TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBreadController;
use App\Http\Controllers\MyBreadController;
public function register()
{
$this->app->bind(VoyagerBreadController::class, MyBreadController::class);
//
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I added Route::get('groups', 'GroupsController@index') as you said in routes/web.php

like this

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();

```
Route::get('groups', 'GroupsController@index');
```

});

and added these lines in index method

public function index(Request $request){

```
    // GET THE SLUG, ex. 'posts', 'pages', etc.
    $slug = $this->getSlug($request);

    // GET THE DataType based on the slug
    $dataType = DataType::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    // Check permission
    Voyager::can('browse_'.$dataType->name);

    // Next Get the actual content from the MODEL that corresponds to the slug DataType
    $dataTypeContent = (strlen($dataType->model_name) != 0)
        ? app($dataType->model_name)->latest()->get()
        : DB::table($dataType->name)->get(); // If Model doest exist, get data from table name

    $view = 'voyager::bread.browse';

    if (view()->exists("voyager::$slug.browse")) {
        $view = "voyager::$slug.browse";
    }

    return view($view, compact('dataType', 'dataTypeContent'));

}
```

But getSlug method does not work. This error will be shown
ErrorException in GroupsController.php line 23:
Trying to get property of non-object

I guess after overriding Controlles getSlug() does not work and I have to set the slug manually
$slug = 'groups';